# Safari Border-Radius Issues

Tags: safari, css

I'm getting some strange behaviour on Safari with border-radius effecting borders of various elements.

Borders disappear and strange artifacts appear
[image]

Also getting weird double borders, but only sporadically along a div.
[image] What's going on here?