# CSS One border disappears in Safari

Tags: css, border, rounded-corners

I recreated my case here http://jsfiddle.net/eE9cs/

Html:

```
<form id="form_login" name="form_login" method="post">
   <div class="formcontent rounded_corners">
      Content...
   </div>
</form>
```

And css:

```
.rounded_corners{
border: 1px solid #033C64;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius:10px;
}

#form_login .formcontent{padding: 20px; width: 30%; margin-left:30%;}
.formcontent {float:left; margin-bottom:50px;background-color: #F3F6FB;}
```

I have container with borders (on all sides) and rounded corners. The thing is that in Safari right border is not displayed (Everything works fine in FF and Chrome). If I remove rounded corners right border will appear. Also if I remove margin-left css property from the container right border also will appear.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks fine here in Safari (Win7).

Comment: looks fine on safari here too

Comment: Seems related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533731/safari-border-radius-issues

Comment: I tested in Safari on Mac

Answer (score 2):

On the outer div, try this : add overflow:hidden.
Also, you can try box-sizing: border-box.

Anyhow, you can try A LOT of things, but i won't be able to help you out anymore without full code.

Comment: I tried add overflow:hidden to #form_login element but it didn't work.

Comment: I was having issues with an outline disappearing on blur when I didn't want it to in Safari, and adding `overflow: hidden` fixed it. Thanks!